# Does app engine remove html headers from php pages?

Tags: html, pdf, http-headers

I'm using a PHP page that shows a PDF in the browser.
The content of the PDF is in a session variable.

When I use this page on my server, it works perfectly and I can see the PDF as it has to be seen.

When I use this same page on App engine I get "%PDF-1.7 %..."

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the code of the page I use

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<?php
// Inserción de parametros y de funciones
require_once("RKR_P_Parametros.php");
require_once("tUnua_Funciones.php");

session_start();

$ArchivoPDF = LeerVariableSesion("ArchivoPDF");
$NombreArchivoPDF = LeerVariableSesion("NombreArchivoPDF");

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$NombreArchivoPDF.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

echo $ArchivoPDF;
?>
</body>
```

Thank you for your help.

Jean-Daniel Mâlet.

--

Comment: You can't send HTTP headers after you have already outputted data. You are perhaps getting away with it on your server because your output is buffered.

Comment: Hi Phylogenesis, I understand what you wrote but I think that I output the data after I send the headers. I output the data with the last instruction "echo $ArchivoPDF". Am I wrong with that ?

Comment: What about all the HTML you output before the `<?php` tag? That is sent before the PHP code is run. Moreover, all those tags are invalid in a PDF file. I'm actually surprised the resultant PDF file is even viewable by your reader.

Comment: In fact, I'm not generatinf a PDF file, I'm just sending PDF data to the browser...

Answer (score 0):

I'v been investigating around output buffering and I've found a solution which could not be the best...

I first add a php.ini file to my App Engine project :

```
output_buffering = 12288
```

I then modified my php code this way :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<?php
// Inserción de parametros y de funciones
require_once("RKR_P_Parametros.php");
require_once("tUnua_Funciones.php");    

session_start();
$NombreArchivoPDF = LeerVariableSesion("NombreArchivoPDF");

function RKR_VPDF_Callback($Buffer)
{
    $ArchivoPDF = LeerVariableSesion("ArchivoPDF");
    $Buffer .= $ArchivoPDF;
    return $Buffer;
}

ob_start(RKR_VPDF_Callback);

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$NombreArchivoPDF.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

ob_flush();

?>
</body>
```

And it worked.